# Undefined function

Tags: functions, terminology

If we have an element of the set of real numbers i.e. '-3' and we have the square-root function i.e. $f(x) = \sqrt x$, then $f(-3) = \sqrt {-3}$ is undefined and the ordered pair $(-3, \sqrt {-3})$ is not a member of $f$. Is it what an undefined function is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x) = \sqrt x\quad$ IS defined for all $\;x \geq 0,\;$ but is not defined for real numbers $\;x \lt 0$.

So there is a domain on which it is defined, and an interval on which it is not defined.

If a function is undefined, it is usually "relatively" undefined on an interval or at certain points. whether and/or where a function is undefined depends on the given *domain* of the function. In your case  $f(x) = \sqrt x$ is perfectly defined on the set of non-negative real numbers, on the set of natural numbers, on the set of non-negative integers, etc. But it is undefined for all real negative numbers.

So you're correct, $(-3, \sqrt {-3}) \notin f$, but we do have $(3, \sqrt 3) \in f$.

---

Another example: Let $$f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R,\;\;f(x) = \dfrac 1x.\;$$ Then, when $\;x = 0,\;\;f(0) = \dfrac 10\;$ is *undefined*, because *division by zero is undefined*. But $f(x) = \dfrac 1x$ *is defined* for all other values of $x$: So the domain on which $f$ is defined, i.e., the values of $x$ for which $f$ is defined, includes all $x\in \mathbb R,\;x\neq 0$.  As suggested in a comment below, one way to put this is that no ordered pair of the form $(0, \cdot)$ is a member of $f$.

Comment: Why can't we just define $f(3) : = c$ (in the first example), for some real value of $c$? Or can we?

Comment: For your second example, it might be clarifying to say that "no ordered pair $(0, \cdot)$ is a member of $f$."